# mysql - avoiding filesort due to invalid index..?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, filesort

I am running a query joining multiple tables through a date range search and stuck trying to figure out how to further optimize it.

```
SELECT ACC.name AS account_name, CAMP.account_id AS account_id,CAMP.name AS campaign_name,CAMP.id AS campaign_id,ADG.id AS adgroup_id,ADG.name AS adgroup_name,KW.text AS keyword_name,
SUM(SPENT.billed_clicks) AS billed_clicks,KW.id AS keyword_id,KW.status_id AS status_id FROM account ACC, campaign CAMP,adgroup ADG,adgroup_keyword KW INNER JOIN keyword_spent SPENT
ON KW.id = SPENT.keyword_id WHERE     summary_date >= '2012-03-01' AND summary_date <= '2012-03-04' AND KW.adgroup_id = ADG.id AND ADG.campaign_id = CAMP.id AND CAMP.account_id = ACC.id
GROUP BY keyword_id
```

The EXPLAIN on this yields the following -

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key          | key_len | ref                             | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | SPENT | range  | summary_date               | summary_date | 3       | NULL                            | 752191 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | KW    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK1948D0E6ED3A5544 | PRIMARY      | 8       | clicksummarydb.SPENT.keyword_id |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ADG   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FKBBC2083C29112FD0 | PRIMARY      | 8       | advertisedb.KW.adgroup_id       |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CAMP  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FKF7A90110246F33C4 | PRIMARY      | 8       | advertisedb.ADG.campaign_id     |      1 |                                              | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ACC   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY      | 8       | advertisedb.CAMP.account_id     |      1 |                                              | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The keyword_spent table contains more than 1.5 million rows and here is the show create table on it

```
 | keyword_spent | CREATE TABLE `keyword_spent` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `summary_date` date NOT NULL,
   `adgroup_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `keyword_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `billed_clicks` int(11) default NULL,
   `un_billed_clicks` int(11) default NULL,
   `spent` decimal(20,5) default NULL,
   `last_click_recno` bigint(20) default NULL,
   `campaign_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `account_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `total_convs` bigint(20) unsigned default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `keyword_spent_uniq` (`summary_date`,`adgroup_id`,`keyword_id`),
   KEY `idx_account_id` (`account_id`),
   KEY `idx_kw_id` (`keyword_id`),
   KEY `adgroup_id` (`adgroup_id`),
   KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`),
   KEY `summary_date` (`summary_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I don't understand why near 750,000 rows are being scanned when there are no more than 100,000 records in that date range.

Also, why is it doing a filesort instead of using indexes. ?

Comment: First thing to do is get rid of the From A,B,C stuff and use inner join On for each one, so your where clause is just on summary_date.

Comment: @Tony: I concur. I much prefer the `JOIN ... ON` syntax over using the comma style join sytnax. BTW... the predicate on `summary_date` could just as easily be included in the ON clause of the JOIN, doesn't have to be in a WHERE clause, there doesn't need to be any WHERE clause at all.

Comment: I re arranged the query per both suggestions. Just curious, Apart from looking cleaner, does it give any perf boost.?

Comment: Maybe, the cleaner the query the more chance the dbms has to wade through it and do something sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File sorts aren't necessarily bad. As shown in [Baron Schwartz's blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/), file sorts aren't necessarily about files. It's just a quick sort that is used when there are no valid indexes available.

As an idea for how to optimize: perhaps have all of the aggregate data be in its own subquery, and join that data? I'm thinking something like this (make adjustments as needed):

```
SELECT ACC.name AS account_name,
CAMP.account_id AS account_id,
CAMP.name AS campaign_name,
CAMP.id AS campaign_id,
ADG.id AS adgroup_id,
ADG.name AS adgroup_name,
KW.text AS keyword_name,
KW.id AS keyword_id,
JOINED.billed_clicks AS billed_clicks,
JOINED.un_billed_clicks AS un_billed_clicks,
JOINED.total_clicks AS total_clicks,
JOINED.spent AS spent,
JOINED.total_convs AS total_convs
FROM account ACC
INNER JOIN campaign CAMP ON ACC.id = CAMP.account_id
INNER JOIN adgroup ADG ON CAMP.id = ADG.campaign_id
INNER JOIN adgroup_keyword KW ON ADG.id = KW.adgroup_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    SUM(billed_clicks) AS billed_clicks,
    SUM(un_billed_clicks) AS un_billed_clicks,
    SUM(billed_clicks) + SUM(un_billed_clicks) AS total_clicks,
    SUM(spent) AS spent,
    SUM(total_convs) AS total_convs,
    id AS keyword_id
    FROM keyword_spent
    GROUP BY keyword_id
) JOINED ON JOINED.keyword_id = KW.id
```

Hopefully I'm understanding this right. There is one benefit to this solution: the group by/aggregates are kept separate, and you don't have to worry about group by-ing the other columns, which you never did in the original example.

Comment: thats an interesting idea. Will try it out.

Comment: @Wolfmann2000 , using your query model along with creating a composite index on (keyword_Id, summary_date) brought down the exec time from 35 seconds to just 6 seconds.. !! So, thanks for that. However, Im unable to understand how this query is different in terms of execution compared to my version apart from rearranging. Could you help me understand. ? In fact, the EXPLAIN for your query shows me additional scans, so im confused.

Answer (score 2):

Try an index on all of the columns referenced in the join predicates:

```
CREATE INDEX keyword_spent_IX2 ON keyword_spent (keyword_id, summary_date)
```

-or-

```
CREATE INDEX keyword_spent_IX3 ON keyword_spent (summary_date, keyword_id)
```

-or- you could even create a covering index that includes all of the columns referenced in the query:

```
CREATE INDEX keyword_spent_IX4 ON keyword_spent (keyword_id, summary_date,
    billed_clicks, un_billed_clicks, spent, total_convs)
```

---

The filesort operation is likely due to the GROUP BY.

My preference is to use the `JOIN ... ON` syntax rather than the old-school comma and mixing the join predicates in the WHERE clause.

```
  FROM account ACC
  JOIN campaign CAMP ON CAMP.account_id = ACC.id
  JOIN adgroup ADG ON ADG.campaign_id = CAMP.id
  JOIN adgroup_keyword KW ON KW.adgroup_id = ADG.id
  JOIN keyword_spent SPENT ON SPENT.keyword_id = KW.id
 WHERE SPENT.summary_date >= '2012-03-01'
   AND SPENT.summary_date <= '2012-03-04'
 GROUP BY SPENT.id
```

You are grouping by only a subset of the non-aggregates in the SELECT list. Most other RDBMSs will throw an exception on this; MySQL is more liberal.

Comment: Ah.. I didnt see the keyword_id has to be indexed. I will try it and see how it goes.

Comment: @Anand: If you want to avoid the filesort, try an index with the "GROUP BY" column as the leading column.

Comment: I created an index (keyword_id, summary_date), since my original query grouped by keyword_id. It didnt get rid of the filesort.

Comment: @Anand: a filesort is not evil. It may be the fastest way for MySQL to get the result.  Is the explain plan showing your query using the new index?

Answer (score 1):

Try with an index on summary_date first (it is used in the where), then keyword_id; and explicitly moving the date range inside the JOIN:

```
ON (SPENT.id = KW.id AND SPENT.summary_date BETWEEN ... AND ...)
```

Also, try creating a VIEW giving you the aggregate fields on SPENT. Ideally this should be better understood by the optimizer and save you some time.

```
CREATE VIEW SPENT AS SELECT
    keyword_id,
    SUM(SPENT.billed_clicks) AS billed_clicks,
    SUM(SPENT.un_billed_clicks) AS un_billed_clicks,
    SUM(SPENT.spent) AS spent,
    SUM(SPENT.total_convs) AS total_convs
FROM keyword_spent GROUP BY keyword_id;
```

This requires an index on keyword_id first and summary_date second, and the JOIN with the VIEW should be equivalent to a SELECT of 100,000 rows.